# Where does an element with a property of inherit get its value from if ascendants also have that property value set to inherit

Tags: html, css, inheritance

To my understanding, if a property is not declared for an element in the DOM during the cascade, then a specified value, `inherit` or `initial`, will be used for the property. The reasoning behind having specified values is so that all properties will end up with **some** sort of value.

So I got curious, if an element has a property with a specified value of `inherit`, and all of its ascendants also have a specified value of `inherit`, where does the original element get its value from?

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance#inherited_properties) says the root element of the document (html element) will always have the `initial` value for its specified value. This would make sense, as the inherits from the original element would propogate up until it reaches the html element, which would have `initial` as the value for the property, then the original element would take on this `initial` value.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<body>
        <h2>Contact Form</h2>
</body>

</html>
```

e.g Given this HTML document, the h2 element has no user agent declarations and I haven't added any author declarations for the property of `text-align`. `text-align` has a specified value of inherit, so it tries to inherit from the `text-align` of the body element, which itself has a value of inherit. The body element then tries to inherit the `text-align` value from the html element, but since the html element is the root element, its `text-align` value is `initial` which is to align leftwards, so then the body element inherits that `initial` value from html, and the h2 inherits that `initial` value from the body element.

Now, I then got curious and decided to experiment with what would happen if I set the html element's `text-align` to inherit as well, where would the h2 element get its `text-align` value from then?

```css
html {
    text-align: inherit;
}
```

The h2 element seems to just go with the 'initial' value of `text-align`. Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#inheriting):

> For the root element, which has no parent element, the inherited value is the initial value of the property.